# Declaring and using array of structures in Arduino

Tags: programming, array

Printing structure variables, I get default values. What is wrong with my code?

```
struct SCENARIO
{
  int Lamp_Pin = -1;
  int PB_Pin = -1;
} ;

SCENARIO  _red;
SCENARIO  _yellow;
SCENARIO  _white;
SCENARIO  _stop;
SCENARIO btns[4] = { _red,  _yellow, _white, _stop};


void setup()
{ 
  _stop.Lamp_Pin = 8;
  _stop.PB_Pin = 4;

 ///// initializing other 3 objects i.e. red & white & yellow
 //// 
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
    Serial.print(i);Serial.print(":");
    Serial.print(btns[i].Lamp_Pin);Serial.print(":");
    Serial.println( btns[i].PB_Pin );
    //pinMode(  btns[i].Lamp_Pin, OUTPUT);
    //pinMode(  btns[i].PB_Pin, INPUT);
  }
}
```

The image below shows what I get. It seems I have not initialized the variables!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a struct is handled as a value type, not as a reference type.

This means that a copy of `_stop` is made and put in `btns` (`btns[3]` actually).

So what you need to do is putting pointers into the `btns` array:

```
SCENARIO* btns[4] = { &_red, &_yellow, &_white, &_stop};
```

The symbol * denotes a pointer, and & means the address of a variable (so it points to the variable and is not a copy).

Now when you change `_stop`, also `btns[3]` which points to `_stop` will show the correct initialized value.

For printing you should use:

```
Serial.println( (*btns[i]).LampPin);Serial.print(":");
Serial.println( (*btns[i]).PB_Pin );
```

Because *btns[i] is a pointer, but because this is a very often used feature, a special notation can be used:

```
Serial.print(btns[i]->Lamp_Pin);Serial.print(":");
Serial.println( btns[i]->PB_Pin);
```

Comment: Thanks! Coming from managed world, I forgot the pointers behavior!

Comment: @BehzadSedighzadeh Luckily in C# they don't exist anymore, but with programming lower level devices, you don't want to rely mostly on automatic memory allocation and garbage collection and pointers are 'directly to the point(er)'.

Comment: If an answers helped you, upvote it (arrow next to the question), for the best answer, accept the answer (under the arrows next to a question).

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
SCENARIO btns[4] = { _red,  _yellow, _white, _stop};
```

you are making 4 copies of the structures and placing them in an array.

Instead you should either create the array directly with the values:

```
SCENARIO btns[4] = {
    {-1, -1},
    {-1, -1},
    {-1, -1},
    {8, 4}
};
```

And only use the array, or use pointers in the array:

```
SCENARIO *btns[4] = { &_red,  &_yellow, &_white, &_stop };
```

and then access the entries as pointers:

```
Serial.print(btns[i]->Lamp_Pin);
Serial.print(":");
Serial.println( btns[i]->PB_Pin );
```

Comment: Thanks. I mostly code in C# and in this case I had forgotten Array of structures looks different than managed world!